# How to resize modal in same page in ionic?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

For the continuation of my feedback form app, I have another question on how to resize a modal, I know there are suggested answer here in stack overflow but it seems I can't apply on my issue.

The scenario is, **Feedback Form (Modal1)** will display once the user access the feedback form, then once the user submitted their feedback **Thank you (Modal2)** will display. But my problem is *Modal1* has different size compare to *Modal2*. How will I customize the size of *Modal2* only.

I have a custom class for `global.scss`. This is use for a uniformed modal lay out. But I only need one (1) small modal. How will I customize it for a certain modal like the layout for **Thank you modal** ?

Thank you

**global.scss**

```
.my-custom-class .modal-wrapper {    
    --height: 90%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 5%;
    --width: 90%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: block;
 }
```

**Feedback Form Modal 1**

[image]

**Thank you Modal 2**

[image]

**.html**

```
 <ng-template #thanksContent>
  <ion-grid class=" ion-hide-lg-down">
    <ion-text class = "indent-left"><h2><b>Feedback submitted.</b></h2></ion-text>
      <img class = "center" src = "{{assistantThankyou|staticpath}}"/>   
  </ion-grid>
  </ng-template>
```

I tried to add `<div class = ""modal-size>` in my html but nothing happens.

Hope you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

if you are creating modal using ionic ModalController then just apply cssClass which you are write in global.scss file.

for example

```
const modalCtrl = await this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: modalComponent,
  cssClass: 'my-modal-class'
})
```

global.scss

```
.my-modal-class{
 .modal-wrapper{
  height: 30%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}}
```

Comment: how will I use that code, if I only need it that specific response of Thank you modal?

Comment: .my-modal-class{
  .modal-wrapper{
    height: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }} hope this will help you

Comment: if I will edit the `global.scss` will that affect the rest of the modal in my app? All I need to resize is just the *Thank you modal*

Comment: check i have edited my answer in global.scss file you need to specify custom class name and than apply your custom thank you modal css in this class. as per my example. it won't apply to all the modal

Answer (score 7):

That old example in [Ionic 5's documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/api/modal#customization) from your question did not work for me. This is the correct way to target the shadow part that has the `.modal-wrapper` class in [Ionic 6](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#css-shadow-parts):

```
ion-modal.my-custom-class::part(content) {    
    --height: 90%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 5%;
    --width: 90%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: block;
 }
```

Comment: this solutions is working good in my project. I am using ionic 7.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `height` of Modal. ***Ionic 6+***

*.ts*

```
 const modal = await modalController.create({
    component: CreateExpenseTemplateComponent,
    cssClass: 'create-expense-template-modal',
  });
```

*.global.scss*

```
 ion-modal.create-expense-template-modal {
        --height: 750px !important;
    }
```

Comment: working for me in Ionic v 7.4

Answer (score 1):

For ionic 6 in global.css

```
.my-custom-class {
  &::part(content) {
    width: 200px
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic offers [CSS properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#css-custom-properties) for this

```
.modal-wrapper {
  --width: 90%;
  --height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: I'd hoped this would work for me but it doesn't. Where should I place it?